# String to Int Conversion in Arduino

Tags: string, arduino, char, int

I' am trying to convert string to int(like Integer.parseInt() in java) in arduino in order to make some operation's on the numbers. Unfortunately none of my solution's worked.
Until now I tried:

Create char Array and call atoi function:

```
String StringPassword;

uint8_t *hash;
//Here I define hash

int j;
for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
 StringPassword.concat(hash[j]);
}

 //Checking String Size
 Serial.println("Size");
 //Checking String
 Serial.println(StringPassword.length());
Serial.println(StringPassword);

int jj;
char PasswordCharArray[StringPassword.length()];
 StringPassword.toCharArray(PasswordCharArray, StringPassword.length());

awa = atoi(PasswordCharArray);  
Serial.println(awa);
```

Output:

Size
48

168179819314217391617011617743249832108225513297

18209

Create char Array for null terminated string and call atoi function:

```
 String StringPassword;

 uint8_t *hash;
 //Here I define hash

int j;
for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
 StringPassword.concat(hash[j]);
}

 //Checking String Size
 Serial.println("Size");
 //Checking String
 Serial.println(StringPassword.length());
Serial.println(StringPassword);

int jj;
char PasswordCharArray[StringPassword.length()+1];
 StringPassword.toCharArray(PasswordCharArray,StringPassword.length()+1);

awa = atoi(PasswordCharArray);  
Serial.println(awa);
```

Output:

Size

48

168179819314217391617011617743249832108225513297

-14511

use toInt Function:

```
 String StringPassword;

  uint8_t *hash;
 //Here I define hash

int j;
 for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
   StringPassword.concat(hash[j]);
 }

 //Checking String Size
 Serial.println("Size");
 //Checking String
  Serial.println(StringPassword.length());
Serial.println(StringPassword);

awa = StringPassword.toInt();
Serial.println(awa);
```

Output:

Size

48

168179819314217391617011617743249832108225513297

-14511

What is the proper way of changing String to Int so:

awa = 168179819314217391617011617743249832108225513297 ?

And could someone explain to me why my solution's didn't worked? I tried to use the function's that were mentioned on Stackoverflow and Arduino forum to solve this.

Comment: Java can't convert such big number either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 168179819314217391617011617743249832108225513297 reaches the maximum integer value limit so therefore this will not convert into an integer.

Try using `atol()` instead of `atoi()`. Long numbers can hold more data like the number shown above.

Comment: Even a 128-bit integer can't hold that number.

Comment: Thank You for a reply. I tried to use atol() and long instead of int but it still doesn't work. It gives me -970930351.

Comment: As at the end all I needed with this value was to reduce it's size by awa % 1000000; and compare with hash value generated on server side(php), and recuded by $ReadyPassword = (int)$awa % 1000000; for now instead of using whole hash value I will just take same parts of it on both sides: server and arduino to make 6 digits password from it. Anyway thank You for a reply as otherwise I would be still trying to figure out why it do not work.

Comment: @TheBezwet Why did you accept this answer? It didn't solve your problem. Why are you trying to convert a hash into an integer at all? I think you are having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @TheBezwet It would make more sense to post an answer with your own solution and accept that. Accepting an answer as a thanks is counter productive. That's what upvotes are for.